# Shell Method Hyperbola Question

Tags: calculus, integration

$x^2-y^2 = 7,x =4;$ about $y=5$

How can you solve this problem using shell method? do not evaluate only setup.

Sorry for my grammatical mistakes, my native language is not English.

Comment: I don't understand what the question is.  What are you trying to compute?

Comment: Volume of solid bounded by $x^2-y^2 = 7$ and  $x = 4$  rotating about  $y = 5$

Comment: You might’ve written that in the first place. At least half of the entries in the list of related questions at right are examples of computing volumes using the shell method, and there are more in their related questions list. I suggest you study them and try to solve the problem on your own. You should at least be able to set up the integrals, as you ask in your question, after seeing all of those examples. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3141433/265466 in particular should go a long way toward getting you started.

Answer (score 0):

The statement is not very clear, but as I understand it, the solution follows. I hope it helps. Either way, it serves as a template for similar issues.

$$
2\pi\int_0^{4} (5-y)\sqrt{7+y^{2}}\, dy = 10\pi\int_0^{4}\sqrt{7+y^2}\,dy-2\pi\int_0^{4} y\sqrt{7+y^{2}}\, dy
$$

Now just solve the integrals above. The second integral can use the replacement $u=7+y^2 \to du=2\, dy$. Then,

$$
2\pi\int_0^{4} y\sqrt{7+y^{2}}\, dy = \pi\int_7^{23} \sqrt{u}\, du=\left.\pi\frac{2}{3}u^{\frac{2}{3}}\right\vert_{7}^{23}=\frac{2\pi}{3}(23\sqrt{23}-7\sqrt{7})
$$

The first integral $I= \int_0^{4}\sqrt{7+y^2}\,dy$ you can use first integration by parts:

\begin{eqnarray}
I&=&y\sqrt{7+y^2}-\int_0^{4}\frac{y^2}{\sqrt{7+y^{2}}}\, dy\\
\\
&=& y\sqrt{7+y^2}-\int_0^{4}\frac{7+y^2}{\sqrt{7+y^{2}}}\, dy+\int_0^{4}\frac{7}{\sqrt{7+y^{2}}}\, dy \\
\\
&=& y\sqrt{7+y^2}-I+7\ln\left\vert x+\sqrt{7+x^{2}} \right\vert
\end{eqnarray}

Then,

$$
I= \frac{y}{2}\sqrt{7+y^2}+\frac{7}{2}\ln\left\vert x+\sqrt{7+x^{2}} \right\vert
$$

To finish, just add the results of each integral. 
:-)

Answer (score 0):

The volume integral with the shell method is set up as

$$V=\int_{-3}^3 2\pi r\> h\> dy=2\pi \int_{-3}^3 (5-y) \left(4-\sqrt{y^2+7}\right) dy$$